# set two foreign key attribute as a composite primary key for another table in oracle

Tags: oracle, primary-key, composite-key

I'm having two column in STUDENTSINTEST table as

1.TestID
2.StudentID

both are foreign key for some tables, now i want to know how to set those two column as a composite primary for STUDENTSINTEST table? help are appreciated....

Answer (score 3):

If your table has already been defined

```
alter table STUDENTSINTEST add constraint STUDENTSINTEST_PK primary key(TestID,StudentID);
```

else you can add the following statement to the CREATE TABLE statement

```
constraint STUDENTSINTEST_PK primary key(TestID,StudentID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<%@ page import="com.otts.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.otts.dao.TestProfile" %>

<%-- Variables declaration --%>

<link type="text/css" href="/TandQMgmt/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<link href="/TandQMgmt/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<script src="../js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-validate.js" ></script>



<body>

<div class="contanier">
    <div class="content-beginner">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="heading-bar">
            <div class="heading-text"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>


                                        </ul></div>
                    </li>

                    </ul></div>
                    </li>



                    <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Help & Support </span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


         <script>
$(function() {
    $( "input:submit").button();})
        function validateregisterform(){
    $("form#Formviewtest").validate();
    }
</script>




<% 

if(request.getAttribute("indicator")=="view"){  %>  

<p align="center">



              <table width="800" height="281" border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td height="33" colspan="7" bgcolor="#663300"><h1 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#FFF;">View Test Details</h1></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">TESTID</h2></td>
    <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">TEST NAME</h2></td>
    <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">TEACHER ID</h2></td>
    <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">NO of PARTICIPANTS</h2></td>
    <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">CURRENTLY ALLOCATED</h2></td>
        <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">DURATION</h2></td>
    <td width="96" bgcolor="#e3d5a8"><h2 style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#C30; text-align:center;">CREATED BY</h2></td>
      </tr>
 <%ArrayList userList=null;

userList=(ArrayList) request.getAttribute("totalResultSet");
for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++)
{
    TestProfile testProfile = (TestProfile) userList.get(i);

    %>  

<tr>

  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getTestId());%></td>
  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getTestName());%></td>
  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getTeacherId());%></td>
  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getNumberOfParticipants());%></td>
  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getCurrentlyAllocated());%></td>
  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getDuration());%>    </td>
  <td><%out.print(testProfile.getCreatedBy()); %>   </td>



</tr>


<% }%>
</p>

</table>

<%}
else {  %>





<form name="Formviewtest" id="Formviewtest" onsubmit="return validateregisterform()" action="../TestandQuestionManagement" method="post">
<pre>







                                                  <input type="submit" name ="Submit" value="View Test"></input>  
</pre>


 </div>

    </div>


</div>


</form>

</body>
</html>
<%}%>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is.  If you believe this code is important to your question, please edit your question to include it.  It's not obvious to me, however, how your JSP code has any bearing on the question you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Do You wish to update test details?");
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("Test details updated!");
  }
return false;

}
function validate(form){


    var testName1 = form.testName.value;
    var duration1 = form. duration.value;
    var noofParticipants1 = form.noofParticipants.value;
    var teacherId1 = form.teacherId.value;

    if(testName1.length==0){
         alert("Please  enter a Test name");
          return false;
    }
    if(testName1.length>10){
         alert("Please  enter a Test name lessthan or equal to 10");
          return false;
    }
    if(duration1.length==0){

         alert("Please  enter a test duration");
         return false;
    }
    if(duration1/1!=duration1){
         alert("Please enter a test duration in numbers");
         return false;
    }
    if(duration1<15 )
    {
         alert("Please enter a test duration greater than 15");
         return false;
    }
    if(duration1>300 )
    {
         alert("Please enter a test duration less than 300");
         return false;
    }
    if(noofParticipants1.length==0){
         alert("Please  enter a number of participants");
          return false;
    }
    if(noofParticipants1/1!=noofParticipants1){
         alert("Please enter a number of participants in numbers");
         return false;
    }

    if(teacherId1.length==0){
         alert("Please enter a Teacher Id");
          return false;
    }
    if(teacherId1/1!=teacherId1){
         alert("Please enter a teacher Id in numbers");
         return false;
    }

    return true;

}


</script>
<title>Update test</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static   String DRIVERNAME="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    public static   String SERVERNAME = "172.24.137.30";
    public static   String PORTNUMBER = "1521";
    public static   String SID = "ora10G";
    public static   String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + SERVERNAME + ":" + PORTNUMBER + ":" + SID;
    public static   String USERNAME =  "e554893 "; 
    public static   String PASSWORD = "VAnjrmfvi";


Connection conn = null;
        try {
            // load the JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver
            Class.forName(Constants.DRIVERNAME);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Constants.URL,
                    Constants.USERNAME, Constants.PASSWORD);

        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Connection not created");
        }
        return conn;
```